# How to change default db2 database admin username to something else in Linux?

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-10.5

I have a DB2 database version 11.1 on Linux - rhel 7.7 in my test environment. I need help on how to change the default db2 admin username to something else, ie. db2inst1 to dbroot. And the new db2 user - dbroot should have the same privileges which old db2 user - db2inst1 had. Please share the steps to do the needful tasks.

Thanks in advance

Comment: create a new user (os user) and grant dbadm on the database to that user.

Comment: In addition, you may want to transfer ownership on all database objects to that user

Comment: You have to be more precise in what you're asking. Is this about DBADM privileges on a particular database? SYSADM privileges? Instance owner privileges?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to directly rename the db2 instance name, But following steps can be used to move the db to new instance

> Take the backup of DB's and provide 755 permissions to backup images. Offline backup is recommended
>   db2stop command to stop the instance
>   drop current instance name by using db2idrop command
>   create new instance by using db2icrt command
>   once instance is created, switch to the instance id and  please start the instance by db2start command
>   Restore the db to new instance name by using below command incase of auto storage
>    db2 restore db  from  ON  NEWLOGPATH 
>   If there are user defined tablespaces, Which will need redirect restore
>   db2 connect to

or Run below command to grant DBADM access to dbroot.

db2 " grant DBADM WITH DATAACCESS on database to user dbroot";

Answer (score -1):

You may want to create a new instance with instance name as dbroot and then move all your database to new instance dbroot (from current instance db2inst1) using db2relocatedb utility.

Please check: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0004500.html